# Grep Windows Exact Word Match

Tags: grep

I am using windows 10 and I am trying to find an exact word match in a folder with subfolders. I am looking for the word "tip" (not case sensitive). When i search for tip I get a huge list of files that include words like "multiple" I just want the pages that contain the exact word :tip". How can I search for that?
Thank you.

Comment: Just so we're clear, are you actually using `grep`, or some other tool?

Comment: Assuming you are using `grep` or some other regex tool, `\b` is a word boundary, so looking for `\btip\b` should do the trick.

Comment: I am using grepwin.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It works on GrepWin as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am using GrepWin and the answer given above worked fine. `\btip\b`
Thanks again.